# NDsolve for a vector valued function and NDsolve::ndfdmc error

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve numerically an ODE system written in a matrix form where I encounter an error:

[image]

The simplified example:

```
c = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
a = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
b = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

NDSolve[{u'[z] == -z (a . (c*u[z])), u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, u, {z, 1, 2}]
NDSolve[{u'[z] == -z (b . (c*u[z])), u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, u, {z,1, 2}]

NDSolve[{u'[z] == -  (b . (c*u[z])), u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, u, {z, 1, 2}]
NDSolve[{u'[z] == -z (b . (  u[z])), u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, u, {z, 1, 2}]
```

where out of the 4 (nearly identical) equations all work except the second one, which gives the above error with the output

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[1][u][z] == {-6 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z]},u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, u, {z, 1, 2}]
```

I guess `u` is not recognized correctly as a vector in the equation, but why? And why removing `z` or `c` make it work again?

Checked in Mathematica v12.3.1 and v11.0.1.

Comment: I do not see any ODE system. If you type one of your input, say the first one, the ode is `u'[z]== {-5 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z], -5 z u[z]}`  How is this is an ode system? May be if you explain more clearly what are the dependent variables here and the independent variables it will help. I only see `u[z]` everywhere.

Comment: `u[z]` is here a vector and `z` is a dependent variable. As it is written in NDSolveIntroductoryTutorial the NDSolve should automatically understand it as such from the initial condition. What I meant by ODE system is if you consider every component as a separate function. But you can look at it as a one ODE for a vector.

Comment: `u[z] is here a vector and z is a dependent variable`. I do not understand. How could `z` be the dependent variable when you write `u'[z]`? You must be using some notation I am not familiar with here.

Comment: Sorry, yes. `z` is an *independent* variable. Then `u` is a function mapping real numbers to dim 5 vector space, so `u[z]` is a dim 5 vector, e.g. at initial condition `u[1] == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`